# Por qué una imagen horizontal se vuelve vertical cuando la relaciono al html?

Tags: html, css

Sigo practicando con css, html y como manejarlos. Ahora estoy practicando con imagenes de un drive y como linkearlas a un html. Todo había salido bien hasta que subí la tercera imagen que pueden ver en [mi codepen](https://codepen.io/lina-paredes/pen/eQqMov) que aún cuando está originalmente de manera horizontal por alguna razón aparece vertical en la página web.

Si alguien me podría explicar a que se debe esto y como puedo solucionarlo lo agradecería mucho!

Tengan buena tarde :) aquí vuelvo a dejar mi codepen:

https://codepen.io/lina-paredes/pen/eQqMov

Comment: Es muy probable que tu imagen tenga un metadata con esa orientación. Algo simple que puedes hacer es editar la imagen (en Paint) por ejemplo y renombrarla al momento de guardar. También puedes eliminar esos metadatos, con un software o incluso existen páginas web que hacen esa función fácilmente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que tu imagen contiene datos EXIF de rotación.... aqui hay dos posibles soluciones, una mas rapida que la otra... La mas rápida, agrega a tu codigo:

```
img {image-orientation: from-image;}
```

Eso hará que el navegador honre la información EXIF y rote la imagen... el problema es que esta parte del manejo del EXIF no está bien solido, se espera incluso que esa regla que te pasé quede sustituida por atributos en la etiqueta `<img>` (puedes ver al respecto en detalle en https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-orientation ).

Ahora bien... ¿qué haría yo?, editar la imagen... yo particularmente uso GIMP (https://www.gimp.org/), cuando abro la imagen el me menciona si hay información de rotación en el EXIF y me pregunta si quiero usarla, luego puedo rotarla y al guardarla, queda libre de eso... se que hay programas especificos para solo retirar la información EXIF, pero yo prefiero usar algo que ya tengo instalado y que uso para otras cosas.

Espero te sirva de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer tu tercera imagen está rotada (de forma horizontal) debido a la metadata; abrí el link y por unos milisegundos se mostró la imágen horizontal y luego el navegador lee esa metadata y la corrige, poniéndola en vertical; sin embargo el problema se puede corregir así:

```css
body{
 font-family: "Montserrat";
 background-color: #1a1a1a;
 color: #e6e6e6;
}
.thumbnail{
 margin: 100px;
}

.col-lg-6{
 height: 500px;
 text-align: center;
 
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.rotate90 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
   <h1>I´m trying to make this work...</h1>
   <hr> 
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-lg-6">
   <h3>This images works,</h3> 
  </div >
  <div class="col-lg-6">
   <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=10hbQmDtsFkjWxTjJH0q3Sa7VascERgSY">
   </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6">
   <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1BW0_mxwkz-XU3yJbGvy_QW2-L4AP6hHU">
   </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
   <h3>This one too,</h3> 
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6">
   <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1X70mnnPZSTJTEoHtUtlcDfZFC5PWA19d" class="rotate90">
   </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
   <h3>this one doesn't</h3> 
  </div>
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu respuesta! Aun cuando sirve con la imagen, el div con class="thumbnail" en el que está adentro no se modifica. Intente ponerle un clase diferente con las mismas caracteristicas que pusiste pero no funcionó. Sabes que puedo hacer?